# How to manage application Module so that it dose not error out when multiple sessions are accessing the same server instance

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Issue 1 : I have a web-service where I am creating a AM performing DB operations like select queries  and I am releasing the AM

when I test this web-service using Multiple requests accessing the same server instance at a time gap of fraction of seconds I am not able to get expected response for Every call

This Exception is printed in the response :

JBO-30014: The cookie for session ad184ff5-db7f-4946-a90c-12c4b8019433 and application ad184ff5-db7f-4946-a90c-12c4b8019433 cannot be removed from the application pool while it has an application module checked out.

```
                                       class="oracle.jbo.common.ampool.ApplicationPoolImpl"

                            file="ApplicationPoolImpl.java"

                            line="826"

                            method="removeSessionCookie">
```

Issue 2:

While doing multithreading using executor classes I am not able to pass the same AM object to every threads I am forced to create new AM in every thread as it errors out when one threads DB transaction reaches commit and the other DB transaction is half a way which will be interrupted and forced to commit

Is there any way out of this?

As the application is facing outages due to more number of AM's And because of which there are more number of DB connections

Using JDeveloper 11g release 2

Comment: "While doing multithreading..." So you define multiple threads yourself in your web application?

Comment: Yes we are using executor classes

Comment: did you manage to find a fix for issue2 ? We are now facing the same problem in one of our applications